# Angular ng-enter leave flickers on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Basically in latest Chrome and IE the views are loaded without problems but in Mozilla Firefox once you click it flickers you the halfloaded-css/js page then disappears and the correctly formed page appears.

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div style="width:100%" ng-view class="view"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .view.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
    -ms-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
    -o-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
    animation-name: fadeOutUp;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden; 
    display: none;
}
.view.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -ms-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

I googled and tried like different methods for some reason I didn't get it to work. Perhaps someone here knows a sure method!

you can try this out at www.kaidoweb.com by cliking navbars left links.